# How to return proper message on 403 forbidden on MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know I can fill the `ReasonPhrase` property of a `HttpResponseMessage` using Web API Framework. But how can I do the same with the normal "MVC" ?

This is my current code:

```
if (filterContext.Exception != null && filterContext.Exception is ArgumentException) 
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = filterContext.Exception.Message;
    //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(filterContext.Exception.Message);
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    filterContext.Exception = null;
}
```

I also know that the commented line would provide the error message to the client but in the Response body. I don't know if this is the best practice.

What I would like to do is the same as this [link](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=238).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting the details in the body like you are doing in the commented out line. This would also allow you to return objects (serialized to JSON/XML) that contain data necessary to troubleshoot the issue. On the client side I wouldn't expect the reason phrase to give me the full details of the error.

Answer (score 0):

ehy not handle the error directly in your webcofig if you get specific error webcofig shoulld redirect to specific error page

```
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="pagenotfoundlError.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: The application is used as a service so I am not confortable returning html pages for calls that didn't provide all the necessary parameters. I want to return the 403 statuscode along with my model validation message.